# srcset y html map responsive

Tags: html, img

Quiero tener en una imagen distintos enlaces dependiendo la parte que se seleccione.

```html
<img src="img/uno.jpg" usemap="#Superficie" alt="txt de imagen"/>
<map name="Superficie">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 120, 250" href="./pgUno.html"> 
  <area shape="circle" coords="275, 75, 75" href="./pgDos.html"> 
</map>
```

Quiero cargar una imagen distinta según la pantalla o el dispositivo que cargue la página

```html
<img src="img/Uno.jpg" usemap="#Superficie" srcset="imgbf/testUno.jpg 300w, imgbf/testDos.jpg 1000w, imgbf/testTres.jpg 2000w" alt="txt de imagen"/>
```

¿Se puede hacer que cargue una imagen en función del tamaño de la pantalla y en función de la imagen cargada, cargar unas coordenadas?

Al final el resultado que busco es una especie de coordenadas que sean responsive.

Comment: A tu primera pregunta, la respuesta es sí, se puede hacer que las imágenes se muestren en función de la pantalla (una característica de html, sin código añadido). A la segunda, no… al menos no solo en html. Necesitas utilizar javascript para obtener el nombre del archivo de imagen y en función a este obtener las coordenadas.

Comment: Yo lo que haria es poner un enlace en la forma que tu quieras para simular una especie de zona clicable. Sino, te recomiendo que mires https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp donde se explica detalladamente el concepto de <map> y <areas>